# How to close any activity of my application by clicking on a notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

When I click on a notification apply the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

In all "startActivity" of the app I applied the next flag:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

The startActivity my notification does the following: 
Call activity "Splash" and is called "Main".

Casulidad If I was in "Main" pulse notification, closes the current (working properly). 
But if I am in the activity "News" and pulse the notification, I have 2 activities open, the new "Main" and the former "News".

How to close any activity of my application by clicking on a notification?

Answer (score 8):

You could set a PendingIntent in the notification that would be caught by the Activity in a broadcastReceiver. Then in the broadcastReceiver of the activity, call `finish();`
This should close your activity.

i.e.
Put this in your activity

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }

};
```

This in your `onCreate()`

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And then your PendingIntent in your notification should have action of `"android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY"` and for safety a package of your activity's package.

This is done by

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 , intent, 0);
```

Then add it to your notification by using the `setContentIntent(pIntent)` when building the notification with the Notification.Builder.

Comment: Thanks, but How do I add "android.intent.CLOSE_ACTIVITY" the intent /pendingIntent notification ? @Woodi_333

Comment: Edited to include how to create pending intent.

Comment: My activity (Main) needs extends from BroadCastReceiver?

Comment: No, just create a sub class and then register it in the activity. It's the first 2 code segments of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I used a singleton with a static flag exitApp that was false at start of the application and it is set to true in the activity that returns from the notification.

This flag is checked in each of onResume() of all activities and if it is true the activity calls it's finish() method..

This way, even if the notification is activated some few activities down the road, each activity finish() and the onResume() of the parent activity is called which in turns also finish() until the mainActivity finish() and the application is terminated.