# how to make pressing on the notificaton text close the app not open other activity

Tags: android, notifications, flashlight

I am developing a flashLight app and I faced a problem in notification which is : When I press the notification text I want to turn of flash and close the whole app , How can I modified the notification method to do that ??
I tried to make anthor activity and put turn of and close app methods in it, but it does not work .
please help and thanks in advance .

this is my notification method

```
public void getNotification()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_ticker_msg));
    // Build the notification:
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Get the notification manager:
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Publish the notification:
    final int notificationId = 0;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same `Activity`, then the `onCreate` method will be called again. You can send one `extra` with your `Intent` that indicates it is an `Intent` generated from the click of notification. In your `Activity` `onCreate`, check for this extra and call `finish()` if it is present.

```
public void getNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FlashActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("origin", "notification");

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notification_ticker_msg));
    // Build the notification:
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Get the notification manager:
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Publish the notification:
    final int notificationId = 0;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

And in your `onCreate` method in `FlashActivity` check the extra.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    if("notification".equals(getIntent().getStringExtra("origin"))) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: You copied from OP "Intent intent = new Intent();" - maybe better something like "Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);"

Comment: Right, and even I believe, it will be better for them to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK.

Comment: about the flags - they seem to be ignored when used with a notification (although they work when used with home screen widget)  I just tried to use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" from a notification and *it re-created the activity* anyway. The same goes for "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP". Would be better to avoid that if you're just going to finish the activity but I don't know how.

Comment: Makes sense. And looks like FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TASK is deprected.

Comment: So I think the best you can do performance-wise is to check the Intent before "setContentView()".

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jaibatrik , but it does not close the activity just restore the activity and the flash is on

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use finish() on your Activity when the notification ils pressed.

EDIT: [How to close any activity of my application by clicking on a notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243137/how-to-close-any-activity-of-my-application-by-clicking-on-a-notification/19243291)

Comment: A flashlight app is typically a one-activity-app. If you have more than one activity, the link you posted is helpful (but being just a link it should have been posted as a comment, not as an answer). If you want to finish just one activity, the methods suggested there are way too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use PendingIntent.

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 resultIntent.putExtra("FINISH",true);
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

// Build the notification:
    Notification notification = builder.build();
//rest of your methods to show notification
```

In your `MainActivity` update depending on your code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("FINISH"))
        {
           finish();
        }
    }


}
```